# How to dynamically hide an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, visibility

I have a web page where you can log in with your account. The idea is that when you press your name a small square appears (similar to what Stack Overflow does) with some of your basic information (name, email, etc.) It's a mix of PHP, CSS and Javascript but the PHP is only to chose the name of the user. So, I have the following code:

```
<style type="text/css">
table.UserInfo
{
    background-color:#000;
    width:100;
    height:100;
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
}
p.UserText
{
    color:#FFF;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser()
{
    //Unknown code here
}
</script>
```

In some part of the page...:
Welcome  visitor !

The visitor is actually set via php to a user that logged in or visitor if there is none. Here is the box:

```
<table class='UserInfo' id='UserInfo' >
<tr>
<td><p class='UserText'>This user is a guest user. There is no information available.</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So, I need the box to appear when I press visitor, so the code would go in `showUser()` and I need to know where I have to put my Javascript code so the box is initially hidden.

For the box showing when I pressed it I tried putting this code in the `showUser()` function:

```
document.getElementById('UserInfo')style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

But it didn't work. I put it hidden because it starts of as visible.

Comment: That is the correct way to do it but you lost the dot between the get element by id and the style

Comment: Thanks, every source I found did not to put the dot. Also, do you know where to put the code for the javascript to set it as initially hidden, besides de onLoad function in the body tag?

Comment: you can put that directly into the html styles... just put a class with the visibility:hidden or inline it on the element you want.

Comment: Could you put it as an answer? I liked it. And I would like to put it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct way to do it but you need to have a dot between the getElementById and the style property for the javascript code to work.  If you want to have the element start off as hidden either give it a class where

```
visibility:hidden;
```

or you can put it as the inline style for the hidden element.  You could also do it in javascript when the load event fires but it is better to do it in the html because if the page takes a long time to render then the user will see what was supposed to be hidden until the ready event fires.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 9):

You could also do this:

```
var_name = document.getElementById("idname").style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: I was trying to hide a div onclick, this is the only way it worked, I was trying visibility = "hidden". Javascript can get really awkward sometimes, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score -1):

Or jquery:

```
$('.anyClass').fadeOut('fast');
```